# Can linux be run on a flash drive long term

Tags: partition, hard-disk, flash-memory

I have an arch install with the root partition on a flash drive.

Additionally, I have an external hard drive which has my HOME and SWAP partitions on it.

I have read online that using a flash drive for swap can prematurely wear out a flash drive, is this also the case for the OS install? Is there any advantages/disadvantages of moving my root partition to the HDD or can flash drives be used for a more long term time from to store and OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash drives are based on flash memory which has a limited number of write-erase cycles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Memory_wear
However, I believe this is less of a problem with modern flash memory.

Most Linux distributions follow the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). If you read through the descriptions you can see that `/var` is used for variable data. Variable data, as the name states, changes often and therefore causes lots of writes to the storage device. To reduce wear on your flash drive you should move `/var` to a separate storage device.

Depending on the amount of memory your computer has you could also consider disabling swapping. This can be done using the `swapoff` command.

You may be interested in reading the following pages on the Arch Wiki:

Installing Arch Linux on a USB key: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key

and

Improving performance (section about reducing disk read/writes): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance#Reduce_disk_reads.2Fwrites

I have been running an Arch Linux installation on a cheap Kingston flash drive for a little over two years now without a problem, without any extra storage!

Comment: Alot of good information here, I am familiar with the general directory structure of linux systems. Just out of curiousity did you keep your `/var` directory on the flash drive as well?

Comment: Yes, I did keep the `/var` directory on the flash drive. I did, however, follow many of the recommendations on the Arch Wiki to reduce the number of writes. I disabled file system journaling, disabled swapping, mounted /var/log as a tmpfs (using https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anything-sync-daemon) and so on. I use my flash drive as a desktop, so I'm not really worried about a little data loss. If I ever break the system I can simply restore it using the backup ISO-image I made using `dd` after installing and configuring the system.